# VBA Code to Insert Row Below Middle Row of Data

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a code that will insert a row below the middle of my data.

I used a variable (count0) to hold the number of rows in the worksheet because I will have a different number of rows sometimes. count2 divides it by 2 to get the middle of my data. & then count1 adds 1 to the middle because the EntireRow.Insert function inserts above the row (so inserting above the row before the middle is the same as inserting below the middle).

Here's what I have:

```
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Insert Data")

Dim count0 As Long
Dim count1 As Long
Dim count2 As Long

count0 = Worksheets("Insert Data").Range("A:A").Rows.count
count2 = count0 / 2
count1 = count2 + 1

ws.Range("A" & count1).EntireRow.Insert`
```

Everything compiles but a row doesn't get inserted anywhere in my data let alone underneath the middle row. Any suggestions on how to fix this or a different way of going about it?

Comment: `Worksheets("Insert Data").Range("A:A").Rows.count` - this counts all rows, not the rows with data.

Comment: [How to find the last row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/find-last-used-cell-in-excel-vba)

Comment: `MIDrOW=cells(rows.count,"A").end(xlup).row/2` you would need to get a whole number

Comment: @Davesexcel - I believe OP is silently doing this by using `Long`s.